# How to set html id tag dynamically through angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I know I can set html src tag like `<img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}">`. But how can I set an id tag like `<span id="sourceId::{{post.id}}" class="count"></span>` ?
I tried `<span id="{{ 'sourceId::'post.id }}" class="count"></span>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Basically you should not change Id of elements. it is there to identify the element and get it and manipulate it.

Comment: Agree with @JenishRabadiya, but  `id="sourceId::{{post.id}}"` should set id correctly

Comment: `Thou shall not change ID's` consider using a `data-*` attribute for this kind of situations

Comment: ya agreed that @karaxuna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <span id="{{name}}" class="count">Jeinsh</span>
  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

here is working plunk => [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zb4DdRLWIsh382FxkNqB?p=preview)

Inspect the element in developer tool on span and you will get updated id there.

Answer (score 1):

As @karaxuna said, the following should work

```
id="sourceId::{{post.id}}"
```

Or doing the string concatenation inside the `{{}}` with a `+`

```
id="{{'sourceId::' + post.id}}"
```